# style.pointerEvents not functioning

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an element that shrinks as you click it more and more. Once it reaches a threshold of 1%, it should reappear in full length and not be clickable. the style.pointerEvents is not working. (This is code added in, in order to solve an issue.) This is all of the code, there must be conflicting variables or something. But the main premise is to shake the element and shrink and then regrow and disable itself and after a waiting period enable itself.

`var rotated = false;
var height = 24.6;
var width = 15

```
function clickedhub() {
    clicked();
    timeout();
}

function clicked() {
    document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 10;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
   }
   setInterval(res, 140);
   function res() {
    document.getElementById('box').style = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
    deg = rotated ? 0 : 0;

div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
 }  
}
}


function timeout() {
    document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box');
    width = width / 1.5;
    height = height / 1.5; 
     }
   }

setInterval(gamerule, 10);
   function gamerule() {
        var div = document.getElementById('box');
        if (width <= 1) {
            div.removeEventListener("click", gamerule);
            width = 100;
            height = 100;
    } else {
        width--;
        height--;
    }
    div.style.width = width + '%';
    div.style.height = height + '%';
    div.addEventListener("click", gamerule);
}
```

`

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you

```js
//setInterval(gamerule, 10);
let width = 100;
let height = 100;



var div = document.getElementById('box');

function gamerule() {
    if (width <= 1) {
        div.removeEventListener("click", gamerule);
        width = 100;
        height = 100;
    } else {
        width--;
        height--;
    }
    div.style.width = width + '%';
    div.style.height = height + '%';

}
div.addEventListener("click", gamerule);
```

```css
#box{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#container{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
Click on the red box 
<div id="container" >
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet runs without errors. Most likely the error comes from the the integration with the rest of the code. Please provide your complete code to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: edited code above, the entire script doesnt seem to work at all anymore

Comment: I mean the original code worked itself its just, it wont disable itself so it doesnt fill up all the way and it looks ugly, so why doesnt this work document.getElementById("box").style.pointerEvents = "none";